# Route not defined error in laravel

Tags: php

i'm using form collective in laravel for 2 difference form and got error. Here is my view

```
<div class="table-list-donor">
     {!! Form::model($transactions, ['route' => ['admin.update',$transactions->id ],'file'=>true, 'id'=>'project-form','method'=>'POST']) !!}
     @include('admin.patials.form',['title' => 'edit form','submit' => 'edit'])
{!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

and here is my route

```
<td class="action">
    <a href="{{ route('admin.edit', $history->id)}}">edit</a>
</td>
```

error is Route [] not defined in route . please help!

Comment: post your routes too

Comment: have you named your route ?

Comment: Route::get('/edit/{id}','Admin\AdminFrontEndController@edit')->name('admin.edit')  is my route